# Mongoose is not giving an error but db connection sucessful

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am not getting an error but there is no error either. Basic mongoose code -

```
    const blogs = await Blog.find();

    console.log(blogs);

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        results: blogs.length,
        data: {
            blogs,
        },
    });
```

I am not getting an error. I looked at the collection in compass and even created one. However the response I get is -

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "results": 0,
    "data": {
        "blogs": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Mongoose find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) function returns a Query, not a promise. If you want to use it using `await`, you must add `.exec()` after it. Change your code to `const blogs = await Blog.find().exec();` and it should work.

Comment: I have been using mongoose since a while know however this is the first time I have faced this. Has mongoose gone through an update?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might have been just lucky in your timing. Did you try it with `exec()`? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: No exec() does not make a difference. However my database name had a '-'. When I removed it, the code worked. Pure luck I guess